# How do I call a method from another class in C++

Tags: c++, class

I need help, I want to call generateNumber from a class called MagicNumber in another class called GuessMachine.

MagicNumber class,

```
    int MagicNumber::generateNumber()
    {
        int dice = 1;   
        srand(time(0));
        dice = (rand() % 6 ) + 1;
        return dice;
    }
```

I want to call the above method in the class below, GuessMachine class.

```
    void GuessMachine::checkNumber(MagicNumber& mN, int a)
    {
        int guessNumber=0;
        int tries=0;

        while(nTimes>=tries)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter a number between 1 to 6: ";
            cin>>guessNumber;

            a.generateNumber(); //<-- This is where it went wrong

            tries++;
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: right now, you're trying to call generateNumber() on an int...

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it should be

```
mN.generateNumber();
```

`a` is an `int`.

Comment: That was fast! I still think the above code is pointless, because `mN.generateNumber();` would return an int, and do nothing with it.

Comment: hey thanks. i needed that. the code is not complete anyway

Answer (score 0):

It should be `mN.generateNumber();`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of the MagicNumber class to call a member function. Use something like this:

```
int n = nM.generateNumber();
```